# Prevent ads from showing at the first time in Android app

Tags: android, adview

I'm trying to prevent my android app from showing up ads at the first launch, this is what I have got so far, but it shows ad even in first launch:

```
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);

        Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
        if (ad == interstitial && isFirstRun==false) {
          interstitial.show();

        }
            wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
      }
```

If you guys have better solutions, please share!

Comment: define: "it's doesn't work"

Comment: There is no such error as "doesn't work"

Comment: It's mean the ad show up even it's the first time

Comment: I think the if block never will run. because of this `isFirstRun==false`

Comment: should i change it to isFirstRun!=true?

Comment: I'm going to try with public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
   SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
   
      Log.d("OK", "Received ad");
      if (ad == interstitial && isFirstRun!=true) {
        interstitial.show();        
      }
   wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);      
    }

Comment: How u r comparing `ad` with `interstitial`, which has no data type?? and also in the `if` block you are not changing the preference value of "FIRSTRUN". you r again getting the value from preference. you should set the value to false. and how u r using `this` for getting the `DefaultSharedPreferences` inside a override method `onReceiveAd` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to handle your Ads this way:

```
public void onCreate(){
boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
if (firstrun){
//According to your willing in first run!
//Parts other than ads.
}
else{
//Ads coding in here, such as:
interstitial.show();
} }
```

**Note:** You have to set the firstrun to false after you met the condition. This is about how you will manage the code and in what block you will use it in.